# Puzzling behaviour of two seemingly identical MapReduce functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

Our MongoDB database contains a list of all user accounts, where each new registration has a 'created_at' field in the account document with the current date and time when it was created.

We wanted to find out how many new registrations there were or each day, so put together a MapReduce query to find this out for us.

```
db.accounts.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        var date = this.created_at.toLocaleDateString(); 
        emit(date, 1);
    }, 
    function(key, values) {
        return values.length;
    },
    { out: "output" })
```

Our first attempt was above. For each registration, it emits a value of `1` for that date. The length of each array is then used to determine how many registrations there were on that day.

However, while the results were mostly correct, there were notable inaccuracies. For example the first day gave us a value in double figures when we know the actual figure was far higher. Some values changed after running the map reduce function a second time, despite operating on the same data.

We changed the function to instead sum up the values of the array (which, remember, should only consist of `1`'s and therefore be identical to `array.length`.

```
db.accounts.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var date = this.created_at.toLocaleDateString(); 
        emit(date, 1);
    }, 
    function(key, values) {
        var sum = 0; 
        for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
            sum += values[i];
        }; 
        return sum; 
    },
    { out: "output" })
```

To our surprise, this gave the correct result for every date that was wrong before.

Does anyone know why the first map reduce did not operate as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce may be called multiple times for emit-ed values with later calls being passed the output of earlier calls to reduce.  When you only look at the length of the array, you miss the fact that you may be looking at partially aggregated data.  Summing the values will make the earlier aggregations accumulate, which is what you want.

Comment: D'oh, of course! Knew it was gonna be something embarrassingly simple. Ta!